# An adjective for shopping

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

If culinary is a word related to cooking or food, like a 'culinary experience', what would be a similar word for shopping?

Comment: Mercantile or acquisitory raise their hands first, but perhaps the collective can do better if you provide a little more context for how the word might be used, and what you've already ruled out.

Comment: Shopping experience is what I'd use...what's wrong with it?

Comment: You mean as in ***retail** therapy*?

Comment: @BiscuitBoy points out that attributive nouns work often just as well as adjectives.

Comment: Rob I meant like the city provides an experience which is culinary, (related to shopping)....

Comment: @biscuit nothing wrong just didn't hit me

Answer (score 1):

Just to get the ball rolling...

The common phrase for describing it seems to be "***shopping experience***".

Here's an [**Ngram plot**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=shopping+experience&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cshopping%20experience%3B%2Cc0) for "shopping experince" used in Books from 1960 to 2000.

To re-iterate [@Edwin Ashworth](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/21655/edwin-ashworth), attributive nouns work just fine as adjectives. It's better for you to use "*shopping experience*" for your context.